# What do the 2 different labels on Chappie mean?

Tags: chappie

When they first decommission Chappie a label which reads "Crush" is applied onto its torso. Then further on in the movie we see a second label on its head which reads "Reject".

It was determined by Deon to "salvage the CPU" and "crush the chassis and recycle the alloys". We only see them fix the "Crush" label onto it. There wasn't any scene where they fixed the "Reject" label which also doesn't make sense if the CPU is going to be salvaged.

Does the "Reject" label have any importance or any reference to similar stories/movies?

Answer (score 3):

There is an old Punk Rock movie [*Suburbia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suburbia_%28film%29) in which the characters lived in an abandoned house known as the T.R. or "Total Reject" house. In that movie they actually had to brand "TR" on their arms.

Based on the [Die Antwoord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Antwoord) involvement in *Chappie*, I would not be surprised if *Suburbia* is being referenced.

Comment: Good call. Knowing Blomkamp, there may indeed be more direct references.